# Excel sum different columns if criteria meet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help to sum some numbers for specific criteria.

In Status table,under ID WR, when I enter specific number, what I predifined in Vlook table, I get all data what I need, except quantity what I must enter manualy and that is all fine.

My question wuld be: How to sum specific ID WR with quantity for that ID.

Example:

```
ID WR   8.1  >> how much is total sum for 8.1(not count).
```

Status table

[image: Status table]

Vlook table

[image: Vlook table]

Edit:

I put excel file(Link).On 3 table in excell i wuld need to sum those ID WR.

[Excell table file](https://ufile.io/ordh2)

Comment: `SUMIF` maybe??

Comment: SUMIF with what criteria? ANway thanks

Comment: Sounds like the `ID WR` numbers are your criteria.

Comment: @DulsianRemek first try write the `SUMIF` formula yourself, then post here what you did and someone will point out if you've made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming on your Status worksheet, quantity is in column E, and your ID WR in column A. On your lookup worksheet you would use the following formula (assuming A1 is the ID WR that you want to lookup):
`=SUMIF(Status!$A$1:$A$20;A1;Status!$E$1:$E$20)`

Answer (score 0):

Fix the range and try:

```
=SUMIF(Status!$A$2:$F$5,Vlook!A3,Status!$F$2:$F$5)
```